# Angular reusable class (not the CSS kind)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to have controllers extend some base controller class?  Maybe it's obvious but I'm new to Angular and just haven't found it with searches nor in the Angular docs.  Maybe that's just not how you're supposed to use Angular, but I'm finding myself repeating very similar code.

I'm looking for a way to make a reusable class - as in an Object Oriented class, not the CSS kind.  Maybe the more proper word is Module.  I have something like the following:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <a href="" prev>Prev</a>
    <div ng-model="num">{{items[num}}</div>
    <a href="" next>Next</a>
</div>
<div ng-controller="BarCtrl">
    <a href="" prev>Prev</a>
    <div ng-model="num">{{items[num}}</div>
    <a href="" next>Next</a>
</div>
```

Next and Prev are directives which change the "num" iterator within the applicable scope, which in turn changes the content within the middle div.

The controllers look something like:

```
angular.module("App").controller("FooCtrl", ["$scope", "FooProvider", function($scope, provider) {
   doSomething("abc");
}]);


angular.module("App").controller("BarCtrl", ["$scope", "BarProvider", function($scope, provider) {
   doSomething("xyz");
}]);
```

My question is if it is possible, since they're so similar, to have FooCtrl and BarCtrl extend the same base element which can specify the differences, as a parameter or something, like:

```
var foo = new FooCtrl("abc"),
    bar = new BarCtrl("xyz");
```

I know that new FooCtrl isn't the Angular way but I think by now you get what I'm asking.

Is something like this more what I should be trying:

```
angular.module("app").controller("FooCtrl", ["$scope", "BaseCtrl", function($scope, BaseClass) {
    var foo = BaseCtrl.doSomething("abc");
}]);
```

Comment: it looks to me like you are trying to describe creating a directive... see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I'm a little familiar with directives.  That's how I'm doing the next/prev buttons.  So...  I should create a directive and do something like <div directiveThing="xyz">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are really after is reusing the html template code, but with a different controller, as well as being able to reuse code within each component right?

You could do that like this:

```
angular.module('stackoverflow')
  .factory('somethingService', function() {
     return {
       doSomething: function(input) {
         console.log(input);
       }
     };
   })
  .directive('pagingFoo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div><a href="" prev>Prev Foo</a><div ng-model="num">{{items[num}}</div><a href="" next>Next Foo</a></div>',
      controller: function(somethingService) {
        somethingService.doSomething("abc");
      }}
    };
  })
  .directive('pagingBar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div><a href="" prev>Prev Bar</a><div ng-model="num">{{items[num}}</div><a href="" next>Next Bar</a></div>',
      controller: function(somethingService) {
        somethingService.doSomething("abc");
      }}
    };
  });
```

then call them like this:

```
<html ng-app="stackoverflow">
  <body>
    <paging-foo></paging-foo>
    <paging-bar></paging-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right.  One question - your Bar controller function accepts an argument but it isn't specified anywhere - this is some Angular magic that injects factories to directive controllers?

Comment: Angular does support dependency injection, which is what I used there.  If the string used in the factory definition 'somethingService', matches the string used in the object it's injected into (the directive controllers here), then the object is injected.  You have to use a different syntax if you want it to work when minified ( http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di ), or you can use a tool like ngmin as part of your build to do it (my preferred approach): https://github.com/btford/ngmin